# Link chamar método em Controller - C# MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Tenho uma tabela do MySQL que é mostrada em uma página do meu projeto:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{

   <tr>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nomeMarca)</td>
       <td>
          <a>Deletar</a> &ensp;
          <a>Renomear</a> 
       </td>
   </tr>
```

Quero que quando o usuário clicasse no link com o texto "Deletar" enviasse o item (do modelo "Marca) para o Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RemoveMarca(Marca m)
    {
        MarcasDAO marca = new MarcasDAO();
        int i = marca.deletaMarca(m);
        if (i > 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Message2 = "Marca removida com sucesso!";
            return AddMarca();
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message2 = "Erro ao remover a marca";
            return AddMarca();                    
        }
    }
```

No "marca.deletaMarca(m)" tem o seguinte código para remover a marca da tabela:

```
public int deletaMarca(Marca m)
    {
        try
        {
            comando.CommandText = "delete from Marca where idMarca = @id";
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", m.id);
            comando.Connection = con_sql;
            int i = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            comando.Dispose();
            objcon.Desconectar();
            return i;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Mas não tenho a menor ideia de como fazer isso funcionar. Tentei algumas coisas mas sempre dá erro. Os métodos para adicionar uma Marca estão ok e funcionam pelo site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na sua view, em cada Table row, pode ter...

```
   <tr>
      <% using Html.BeginForm("action","controller", new { Id = item.id }, FormMethod.Post); { %>
         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)</td>
         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nomeMarca)</td>
         <td><input type="submit" value="Remove Marca" /></td>
      <% } %>
  </tr>
```

O método no Controller que recebe o ID...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RemoveMarca(Id id)
{
   int i = marca.deletaMarca(id);        
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

E o deleteMarca pode apenas receber o ID...

```
public int deletaMarca(Id id)
{
    try
    {
        comando.CommandText = "delete from Marca where idMarca = @id";
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", m.id);
        comando.Connection = con_sql;
        int i = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        comando.Dispose();
        objcon.Desconectar();
        return i;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, o jeito que você passou deu certo e funcionou como eu gostaria. Entretanto, ao invés de criar um form para cada linha da tabela, eu coloquei para ser um link assim:  <a href="/Marca/RemoverMarca/@item.id"></a> e deu certo também. Só os codigos que você me passou já deu para ter uma noção. Valeu!